# What's the meaning of the sentence "you're a lot"?

Tags: sentence

I have a doubt regarding the meaning of this sentence "you're a lot" during a film.

Initially I thought that was a compliment, like "you are beautiful",
but it wouldn't make sense with the film scene.

So, I would to ask you if "you're a lot" would mean also something like "you're boring/tedious".

The protagonist was complaining about a situation, and she was really wailing, and her friend said "you're a lot" with rolling her eyes

Comment: This would greatly benefit from an example the use of "you're a lot" in a film. Just by itself it could mean almost anything.

Comment: the protagonist was complaining about a situation, and she was really wailing, and her friend said "you're a lot" with rolling her eyes

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a recent film, it's slang that means they're overwhelming or intense. Here's an article on the phrase: ["What Makes Someone 'A Lot'?", The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/newsletters/archive/2022/04/a-lot-word-etymology/629452/)

> Someone who is “a lot” boils over with their own personality. They may
> be overwhelming and hard to handle in a social situation. They are a
> lot of themselves.

Comment: Strange that someone who's a lot is also unbiddable.

Comment: Also you don't want to leave your car with them...